# Git not ignoring an new untracked file even though it is in .gitignore

Tags: windows, git, gitignore, utf-16

Hi I'm a beginner to Git and am not sure why .gitignore is not working for me when I create new files. I've seen that Git will continue to track files that had previously been staged/committed in the repo but these are NEW untracked files so shouldn't they be ignored. Please help, thanks!

```
>>> echo hello > file1.txt
>>> echo file1.txt > .gitignore
>>> git status
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        .gitignore
        file1.txt
```

Tried to debug by checking git ls-files and double checking the .gitignore contents. However, all seems non-problematic so I'm not sure why the file is not ignored.

I tried adding `*.txt` in .gitignore too to no avail

I used git check-ignore which returns me nothing, so it suggests that the .gitignore is not implemented properly?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. A general rule is to not use *links to images*, but use *text* in your question.

Comment: It looks like you are running windows. Can you check the format of you `.gitignore` file ? for example, from a `git-bash` terminal, run: `file .gitignore`. If it says "UTF-16", you would have to change your file format to UTF-8

Comment: Was UTF-16 your issue ?

Comment: @LeGEC yep, I did as you suggested and saved the file as UTF-8 instead. Thanks much!

Comment: To make your question more directly accessible to others : can you please copy/paste the text from your console (you may edit it from your current `git status`) in your question rather than leaving a link to an image ?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out your issue was another instance of the "gitignore is in UTF-16" issue, which can happen on Windows.

**How can I spot it ?**

One way is to open `git-bash` and use the `file` utility:

```
$ file .gitignore
.gitignore: Unicode text, UTF-16, little-endian text
```

or open your `.gitignore` file in an encoding aware editor (notepad++ or vscode for example) and look at the format detected by the editor.

**How can I fix it ?**

From the command line, you can use `iconv` from a `git-bash` shell:

```
iconv -f UTF-16 -t UTF-8 .gitignore -o .gitignore
```

or from an encoding aware editor, convert the encoding of that file from UTF-16 to UTF-8.